# little doubt for prime integral in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

find a prime integral for the following system $\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^{\prime}=-4 y^3 \\
y^{\prime}=6 x^3+2 x+6 x y^4
\end{array}\right.$

and I have found $\omega=\left(6 x^3+2 x+6 x y^4\right) d x+4 y^3 d y$ but is also $\omega=\left(-6 x^3-2 x-6 x y^4\right) d x-4 y^3 d y$ the same ? Or is there a specific order?

Answer (score 0):

$$4y^3dy+(6 x^3+2 x+6 x y^4)dx=0$$
$$(4y^3dy+6xy^4dx)+(6 x^3+2 x)dx=0$$
$$(dy^4+6xy^4dx)+(6 x^3+2 x)dx=0$$
Multiply by integrating factor $\mu(x)=e^{3x^2}$:
$$(e^{3x^2}dy^4+6xe^{3x^2}y^4dx)+e^{3x^2}(6 x^3+2 x)dx=0$$
$$d(e^{3x^2}y^4)+e^{3x^2}(6 x^3+2 x)dx=0$$
$$d(e^{3x^2}y^4)+d(e^{3x^2} x^2 )=0$$
You can easily integrate.

Comment: In general our teacher says something like this . "Considered the differential form $\omega$ we find if it is closed or not and if not we find an integrating factor and we obtain the prime integral $U(x, y)=e^{3 x^2}\left(x^2+y^4\right)$" when I use the differential form with all minus I obtain the same prime integral with all minus $-U(x, y)$. Are both coorected? $U(x, y)$ and $-U(x, y)$. The prime integral is equal with changed sign?

Comment: if I multipl by any real constant I always will have a prime integral?